# I deleted /etc/php5. How do I restore the folder?

Tags: php

I removed the folder `/etc/php5`, after I removed the `php5` package.  Then I tried to install the package, but it said the folder did not exist.  I looked in trash folder and couldn't find it.  How do I restore the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try purging your package and reinstalling it.

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-common php5
sudo apt-get install php5-common php5
```

Try this.  Note your php5 stuff might get removed and then need to be reinstalled after the fact, because `php5-common` is a dependency for all the other php5 stuff.

Comment: Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini
ERROR: /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini does not exist

Comment: @user118136 take a look at the edit, see if this works.

Comment: php works but not work mysql and phpMyAdmin. May you help me to solve these problems?

Comment: @user118136 those are separate issues and questions, post a separate question for those.

Answer (score 5):

Is some cases the problem is related to the installation system {apt-get, dpkg} which remembers that you have deleted configuration files and make you pay for this sin forever.

Try something like:

```
apt-get install php5-cli php5-comon php5-cli -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confmiss
```

The --force-confmiss flag is supposed to make dpkg reinstall files that where detected as deleted.

Please check out the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/apt-get.8.html) for more information.